# Smarty looping through an array

Tags: php, smarty

I'm a noob to Smarty and am a bit confused as to how best to do this.

Reading the docs I see I have options; section, foreach, foreachelse. Please advise which is the best to use for the below:

I have a PHP script that is giving me an output of something like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [img_name] => f1e9e5f4f48813f98dee066d03d62ea8.jpg
            [orig_img_name] => maria1.jpg
            [txt_under_img] => abc
            [has_comm] => 0
            [usr_album_path] => userAlbums/
            [album_no] => 101
            [username] => Ryann
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [img_name] => ad969040a2362286e5041a6a71f9cd8f.jpg
            [orig_img_name] => maria3.jpg
            [txt_under_img] => def
            [has_comm] => 1
            [usr_album_path] => userAlbums/
            [album_no] => 101
            [username] => Ryann2
        )
)
```

How do I loop through that so I can display it in a neat tabular format?

```
eg:
<img src="{$img_name}">
Img name :{$orig_img_name}
    etc
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it using `foreach` loop:

```
{foreach $array as $item}
   <img src="{$item.img_name}">
   Img name: {$item.orig_img_name} 
{/foreach}
```

Comment: Thanks, will try... but can you tell me why I should not use {section} and what about the array indexes (0,1,2,3 etc) ?

Comment: for different ways to use foreach loops (including keys and values) http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.foreach

Comment: @Ryan I assume you use Smarty 3. Foreach works as in in PHP - you don't need to have indexes here but if you need them you can use `as $index => $item`. Section cannot loop when you don't have numerical indexes in the predictable patter. Foreach is the best choice

Comment: Thanks! Will check in two mins and then select your answer as it works :)